# MVC 3 Authorize attribute removes the '#' from the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

one of my controller's action has the `Authorize` attribute.

When I enter in that URL

```
http://localhost:39217/MC/MA/10#MyHash
```

it changes to:

```
http://localhost:39217/Access/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f MC %2f MA %2f 10 #MyHash
```

but, after the singing in, due the redirection the `#MyHash` hash is gone. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the # represent an anchor, so it's interpreted as part of the url for the redirect.
I guess you have to change the code that handle the redirect in the LogIn action.